# Sharing an opengl texture on pointer from native java to unity

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, opengl-es

I try to share camera preview from native java to unity.

**Firdt try (create texture in java native code & share they to Unity)**

In  native Java code:

I create new OpenGl texture:

```
private int createExternalTexture() {
    int[] textureIdContainer = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureIdContainer, 0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, textureIdContainer[0]);
    return textureIdContainer[0];
}
```

I launch the camera with this texture

```
...
nativeTexturePointer = createExternalTexture();
texture = new SurfaceTexture(nativeTexturePointer);

mCamera.setPreviewTexture(texture);
mCamera.setPreviewCallback(this);
mCamera.startPreview();
...
```

Now I need to share this texture to Unity. **But without bytes transmit.**

In Unity I create new texture by the ID from Java:

```
int nativeTextureID = androidNativeCamActivity.Call<int>("startCamera");
camTexture = Texture2D.CreateExternalTexture(texWidth, texHeight, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false, true, new IntPtr(nativeTextureID));
rawImage.texture = camTexture;
```

When I try to get the texture bytes

```
camTexture.GetPixels()
```

And this don't work.

**Second try (create texture in Unity, share they to Java native code)**

Unity:

```
Texture2D texture2d = new Texture2D(1920,1080,TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
texture2d.Apply();

nativeCamera.StartCamera(texture2.GetNativeTexturePtr().ToInt32(), w, h);

rawImage.texture = texture2d;
```

Native Java:

```
public int startCamera(int pointer, int w, int h){
    int nativeTexturePointer = pointer;

    SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(nativeTexturePointer);
    camera = Camera.open(0);
    setupCamera(w,h);

    try {
        camera.setPreviewTexture(surfaceTexture);
        camera.setPreviewCallback(this);
        camera.setErrorCallback(this);
        camera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return nativeTexturePointer;
}
```

Multithreaded Rendering is disabled in Unity project.

I will be grateful if you will point out my mistake.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: All OpenGL handles are only valid inside the context they are created in. I'm not sure if you can create a shared context (or something similar) with a Unity3D context.

Comment: Check if you have multithreaded rendering enabled. Disable it if so.